# Embedding PDF documents generated with DOCPDF in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, docx

I am trying to convert set up a CodeIgniter application which can take a .docx document, and using DOCPDF (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), convert it to a pdf, and embed that pdf file in my view.  In my controller, I already can convert the .docx document, however, the only way I can do that is to have it generate a file that is automatically downloaded.

Is there a way in which I can send the file to my view so that it can be embedded?  Or maybe, temporarily retain the file in a buffer or something, that I can then use as the source of my embed tags in my view?  I am quite new at all of this, so I feel I might be missing something easy.

Here is what I have tried so far...

My controller method used:

```
public function resume_viewer()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $pageSettings['module'] = 4;
    $pageSettings['subModule'] = 0;
    $data['pageSettings'] = $pageSettings;

    $this->load->library('docx_reader');
    $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));

    $doc = new Docx_reader();
    $doc->setFile('testDoc3.docx');

    $plain_text = $doc->to_plain_text();
    $html = $doc->to_html();

    $pdf = pdf_create($html, 'testDoc4', false);

    $data['html'] = $html;
    $testEvents = explode("'", $this->input->post('testEventIds'));

    $data['testEvents'] = $testEvents;

    $this->load->view('results/resume_viewer', $data);
}
```

My HTML in the view:

```
<div id="magazine" class="text-center">
    <div>
        <h1 style="margin-left: -350px;">Gerald Cunningham</h1>
        <embed src="my-pdf-file-here" width="600" height="775" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I don't know is how to get the converted pdf file into the embed tag there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 problems. The first is that as far as I'm aware, the element you should be using is the `<object>` element, rather than the `<embed>` element.

```
<object data="my-pdf-file-here.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

  PDF Plugin Not Available

</object>
```

FYI, the text within the element is only shown when the browser cannot display PDF files.

Your second problem is that you really need to be saving the PDF and then loading it as the `src` attribute of the `<object>` element.

Here is an example.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($pdf);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('path/to/file/my-pdf-file.pdf', $output);
```

If you're worried about loads of PDFs being created, you could always log the name and path of the PDF to a database table along with a session/user_id or something and when that session expires, `unlink()` all PDFs created under that session.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Do you, by any chance, know of a way in which .docx files can be embedded directly, without having to convert them to pdf files first?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'd hazard a guess that you could use the same <object> element but with the src attribute pointing to the docx file and the type attribute reflecting the docx mime type. I took a quick stab at Googling what that might be and - though I'm skeptical - it appears to be type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Comment: Thanks once again!  One last quick question, if you don't mind.  In the code sample of the object tag, you have the data attribute equal to the pdf file location, and when describing my second problem, you say that I should load it as a src attribute.  Do they both do the same thing?

Comment: The src attribute is just the path on the server to the file. So yes, you could have two <object> elements, one with the path to the PDF file and one with the path to the DOCX file (and obviously, the respective type attribute).

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the help.